# SQL 'insert into table(values)' using QGIS-modeller

Tags: qgis, postgresql, qgis-modeler

How can I run a precalculated SQL query using QGIS-modeller to insert values in an existing PostgreSQL table?

I know I can use `import layer` in DB-manager to load features in an existing table, but I'm working on a more complex model to import features in different related tables.

For testing purposes I created a simple table called test with 2 fields (name and type) and an autogenerated id-field:

[image]

I have a .dbf with the same attributes that I want insert to the DB-table:

[image]

I made a model that:

1. Refactored the attributes into one field with following expression:

   concat(' (','\'', "name", '\',',"type", ')')

Which gives me this result:

[image]

2. Execute SQL to combine all the features into one:

   select 'insert into test (name, type) values ' || group_concat(sql) || ';' as sql from input1

with result:

[image]

3. PostgreSQL execute SQL to run the calculated SQL query, using a pre-calculated value `attribute(@Execute_SQL_OUTPUT, 'sql' )` (because algorithm output does not work)

[image]

This gives me an error saying:

> can't execute an empty query

Running the query 'by hand' within DB-manager works fine.  So the query is not the problem.

Adding the query into the 'PostgreSQL execute SQL-algorithm' as a value does the job.

**So, how can I get the result from the previous query into 'PostgreSQL execute SQL-algorithm'? Or is it a bug?**

more details:

```
QGIS version: 3.10.2-A Coruña
QGIS code revision: d4cd3cfe5a
Qt version: 5.11.2
GDAL version: 3.0.3
GEOS version: 3.8.0-CAPI-1.13.1 
PROJ version: Rel. 6.3.0, January 1st, 2020
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'insert_into_db' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'input' : 'C:/Users/Pieter/Desktop/GIS/insert_into_db/input.dbf|layername=input', 'qgis:executesql_1:sql_output_concat' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'qgis:refactorfields_1:output1' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT' }

Prepare algorithm: qgis:refactorfields_1
Running Refactor fields [1/3]
Input Parameters:
{ FIELDS_MAPPING: [{'expression': 'concat(\r\' (\',\r\n\'\\\'\', "name", \'\\\',\',\r\n"type", \r\n\')\'\r\n)', 'length': 250, 'name': 'sql', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}], INPUT: 'C:/Users/Pieter/Desktop/GIS/insert_into_db/input.dbf|layername=input', OUTPUT: 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT' }
OK. Execution took 0.012 s (1 outputs).
Prepare algorithm: qgis:executesql_1
Running Execute SQL [2/3]
Input Parameters:
{ INPUT_DATASOURCES: ['NoGeometry?field=sql:string(250,0)&uid={d628877a-93e0-4c53-80d8-39fc2d902fd1}'], INPUT_GEOMETRY_CRS: None, INPUT_GEOMETRY_FIELD: '', INPUT_GEOMETRY_TYPE: 1, INPUT_QUERY: 'select \'insert into test (name, type) values \' || group_concat(sql) || \';\' as sql from input1', INPUT_UID_FIELD: '', OUTPUT: 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT' }
OK. Execution took 0.234 s (1 outputs).
Prepare algorithm: qgis:postgisexecutesql_1
Running PostgreSQL execute SQL [3/3]
Input Parameters:
{ DATABASE: 'postgis_25_sample', SQL: None }
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.10/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\postgis.py", line 840, in _exec_sql
cursor.execute(sql)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't execute an empty query

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.10/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\PostGISExecuteSQL.py", line 71, in processAlgorithm
db._exec_sql_and_commit(str(sql))
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.10/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\postgis.py", line 852, in _exec_sql_and_commit
self._exec_sql(c, sql)
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.10/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\postgis.py", line 843, in _exec_sql
+ e.cursor.query.decode(e.cursor.connection.encoding))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'

Error encountered while running PostgreSQL execute SQL
Error encountered while running PostgreSQL execute SQL
Execution failed after 0.47 seconds

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'insert_into_db' finished
```

Comment: For my own benefit, why aren't you doing any of this in PostgreSQL/PostGIS itself?

Comment: @DPSSpatial. Because I have shapefiles and related tables that need to be processed before I can put them into DB.  I want to make a workflow where I just need to set some parameters and then let the model do the job.

Comment: But you're running PostgresSQL commands in your screen capture - that should all be done in the DB, shouldn't it? And the other refactor and sql statements also... Just suggesting this could all be simplified and done in the DB...

Comment: @DPSSpatial, I don't see how... Now we do it with FME.  But we probably want to step over to QGIS-modeller.  So I'm figuring out what's possible.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what your workflow is here - you're using QGIS to input values into a stand-alone table (DBF?) then insert that into PGSQL?

Comment: I have a base layer: lines, representing paths.  Then I have different tables: comments, photo, advises,...  These are connected in a 1:N-relation to the lines.  And so I have multiple baselayers with their related tables.  Some of these layers have slightly different features.  So first I need to modify them and then put them all into the database.  My concern here is that I need to preserve the original relation of the baselayer and the connected tables.  I made a workflow in FME that can handle this. But we investigate how we can do it with QGIS-modeller.

Comment: You should be able to build those relationships in pgsql/postgis and expose them in QGIS instead... at least that's what I would do. Depending on how much spatial interaction the data maintenance process needs, you could even get away with altering the source tables in DBeaver instead...